# Session.getPermissions keeps listing xmpp_login even when revoked

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm using the Facebook android SDK to register the *xmpp_login* extended permission, and there a place in my app where I want to be sure that my user still has the permission authorized.

So I made the following test:

1 - I asked for *xmpp_login* with Session.requestNewPublishPermissions
2 - activeSession.getPermissions list successfully *xmpp_login*
3 - Then I revoked the permission from my facebook profile privacy settings
4 - When I ask for activeSession.getPermissions, it still lists *xmpp_login*, even after having cleared the locale facebook session cache with close().

The wierdest thing is that, with the activeSession.getAccessToken(), when I call:
https://graph.facebook.com/me/permissions?ACCESS_TOKEN
xmpp_login does'nt show up (which is the expected behavior)

I can work around that by calling https://graph.facebook.com/me/permissions?ACCESS_TOKEN in my app, but the android SDK should work the same way, shouldn't it?

-EDIT:
I ended up writing the sad solution I explained above ; here it is, for those who experience the same issue:

```
String url = "https://graph.facebook.com/me/permissions?access_token=" + session.getAccessToken();
new AskFacebookIfXmppIsPermittedTask().execute(url);
```

and the asyncTask...

```
private class AskFacebookIfXmppIsPermittedTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {

        try {
            String urlString = urls[0];
            URL url = new URL(urlString);
            URLConnection urlConnection = url.openConnection();
            InputStream in = urlConnection.getInputStream();
            StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
            IOUtils.copy(in, writer);
            return writer.toString();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            return "Unable to retrieve web page. URL may be invalid.";
        }
    }
    // onPostExecute displays the results of the AsyncTask.
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        try {
            JSONObject response = new JSONObject(result);
            JSONArray data = (JSONArray)response.get("data");
            JSONObject permissions = (JSONObject) data.get(0);
            Object xmpp = permissions.get("xmpp_login");

            findViewById(R.id.importFacebookContactsFrame).setVisibility(View.GONE);

            xmppIsIncludedCallback();


        } catch (JSONException e) {

            if(shouldPromptFacebook) {
                List<String> PERMISSIONS = Arrays.asList("xmpp_login");
                    Session.NewPermissionsRequest newPermissionsRequest = new Session.NewPermissionsRequest(thisActivity, PERMISSIONS);
                    Session.getActiveSession().requestNewPublishPermissions(newPermissionsRequest);
            }
        }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your approach is ok. What I don't get is why facebook provides such an error-prone function. Maybe I am missing something as well.

My solution is basically the same as yours, but i used the facebook request class. Thought i share it, just in case.

```
    new com.facebook.Request(session, "/me/permissions", null, HttpMethod.GET, new com.facebook.Request.Callback()
    {
        @Override
        public void onCompleted(Response response)
        {
            GraphObject go = response.getGraphObject();
            JSONObject jo = go.getInnerJSONObject();
            try
            {
                JSONArray ja = (JSONArray) jo.get("data");
                JSONObject perm = ja.getJSONObject(0);
                boolean publish_actions = perm.has("publish_actions");
                if (publish_actions)
                {
                    //you can share 
                }
                else
                {
                Log.i("Test", "Session has no permission");
                Session.getActiveSession().requestNewPublishPermissions(
                                new NewPermissionsRequest(Activity.this, Arrays.asList("publish_actions")));

                }
            }
            catch (JSONException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }).executeAsync();
```